# Parameter validation failed:\nUnknown parameter in input: \"include\", must be one of: cluster, services

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-ecs

I am writing a lambda to update all the services in all the ecs clusters based on their tags. For that I need to extract the tags from the description of the service but the corresponding function gives error.

```
import boto3
import botocore

client = boto3.client('ecs')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

   responseToListClusters = client.list_clusters()                              #gets list of clusters
   clusterArnsList=responseToListClusters['clusterArns']                                   #extracts list of clusterArns
   for CLUSTER in clusterArnsList:

          responseToListServices = client.list_services(cluster= CLUSTER)                     #gets list of services
          serviceArnsList=responseToListServices['serviceArns']                                     #extracts list of serviceArns
          for SERVICE in serviceArnsList:
             responseToDescribeServices= client.describe_services(cluster=CLUSTER,services=[SERVICE,],include=['TAGS',])
             print(responseToDescribeServices)

                 #client.update_service(cluster=CLUSTER,service=SERVICE,desiredCount=1)              #updates all services
```

Comment: As the answer describes, boto3 1.9.42 didn't have the `include` option, see [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.describe_services).

Answer (score 0):

You are encountering this error because AWS lambda by-default runs with older version of boto3.

Currently AWS lamda has following versions :

python3.7

- boto3-1.9.42
- botocore-1.12.42

python3.6

- boto3-1.7.74
- botocore-1.10.74

python2.7

- N/A

Reference : [Lambda Runtimes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html)

To upgrade the boto3 version you can refer to following articles :

[AWS Lambda Console - Upgrade boto3 version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53736963/aws-lambda-console-upgrade-boto3-version)

https://www.mandsconsulting.com/lambda-functions-with-newer-version-of-boto3-than-available-by-default/