# Error in AWS SQS Redrive from Lambda - boto3 AttributeError: SQS client object has no attribute 'start_message_move_task'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-sqs, botocore

I'm trying to execute from an AWS Lambda the method to start [DLQ redrive](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs/client/start_message_move_task.html). According to documentation, boto3 version must be 1.34.44 or higher.
The lambda has 1.34.9 as boto3 version and Python version is 3.8.18.

My code is:

```
import boto3
SQS = boto3.client("sqs")
dlq_queue_arn = "<dead letter queue arn>"
queue_arn = "<queue arn>"

task_handle = SQS.start_message_move_task(
                  SourceArn=dlq_queue_arn,
                  DestinationArn=queue_arn,
              )
```

Error trace is:

```
task_handle = SQS.start_message_move_task(
File "/opt/python/botocore/client.py", line 906, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: 'SQS' object has no attribute 'start_message_move_task'
```

The weird thing is that the code works locally, with the same versions mentioned above.

Comment: How do you know the boto3 version running in the Lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Lambda runtimes - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html), the **Python 3.12** (latest) runtime has `boto3-1.28.72`. Therefore, it does not support this new command.

You will need to package your own boto3 or upgrade it in-place.

See: [AWS Lambda Console - Upgrade boto3 version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53736963/174777)